# Yii - query not working

Tags: yii, yii-components

```
    'idGroup' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Group', 'id_group'),

$archive_news = News::model()->with(array('idGroup','idGroup.name'=>array('distinct'=>true)))->findall(array(
   'condition' => 'EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM data)=:data',
   'params' => array(':data'=>$_GET['id']),

 ));
     foreach ($archive_news as $value) {
            // print_r($archive_news->text);
     echo "<li>".$value->idGroup->name."</li>";
     }
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Any error ?

Comment: `findall(...)` shoud br `findAll(...)`

Answer (score 1):

Change   `findall()` to `findAll()`

**Notice:** `A` is capital letter in `findAll()` method.

Comment: Function names are case insensitive in PHP.